# How to change an image in flutter when pressed?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

So, I am very new to flutter development and I have a doubt on how to change the image when the button is pressed. So, I have like 3 images and I want any random image out of the 3 images to show up when I click on the 1st image.
I will be attaching the part of the code.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
              child: FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Image.asset('images/image1.png'),
          ))
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

first you can store `'images/image1.png'` as variable

```
String default_image = 'images/image1.png';
```

then change the image part to this

```
 Expanded(
            child: FlatButton(
             onPressed: () {
                 setState((){
                      default_image = "images/image-2.png";
                   });
                 },
                child: Image.asset(default_image),
    ),
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it's Stateful widget if not then please make it stateful first

```
String assetPath = "images/image1.png";
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Center(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                  child: FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                     // Your random logic for change the value of assetPath variable
                   setState((){
                      assetPath = "images/image2.png";
                   });
                },
                child: Image.asset(assetPath),
              ))
            ],
          ),
        );
```